# Guidance on the number of http calls; is too much AJAX a problem?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I develop a website based on the way that every front end thing is written in JavaScript. Communication with server is made trough JSON. So I am hesitating about it: - is the fact I'm asking for every single data with http request query OK, or is it completely unacceptable? (after all many web developers change multiple image request to css sprites).

Can you give me a hint please?

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed twitter works with very similar way

Comment: If you search for the definitive, all-embracing answer, here it comes: "It depends."

Comment: ...and it's not a "best practice" to follow: http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

Comment: Please give a example, how many request are you doing? Can you give a hard number? Maby you can implement Json Piggybacking. This means that  you join multiple request together, to reduce the number of small request. Every request that is made will burn cpu time and waste bandwidth, so if you can reduce requests, then you should.

Comment: One thing to watch out for when heavily relying on JS: users that have JS disabled. It's highly discouraged to depend solely on JavaScript. Your site should be able work without JavaScript so search engines can index and spider content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can request multiple related things at once, do it.
But there's no real reason against sending multiple HTTP requests - that's how AJAX apps usually work. ;)

The reason for using sprites instead of single small images is to reduce loading times since only one file has to be loaded instead of tons of small files at once - or at a certain time when it'd be desirable to have the image already available to be displayed.

Comment: Also every request will introduce extra overhead for the connection that will be made. So if you can pack them together as a sprite, it will be more efficiënt in terms of bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends upon the overall server load and bandwidth use.

If your site is very low traffic and is under no CPU or bandwidth burden, write your application in whatever manner is (a) most maintainable (b) lowest chance to introduce bugs.

Of course, if the latency involved in making thirty HTTP requests for data is too awful, your users will hate you :) even if you server is very lightly loaded. Thirty times even 30 milliseconds equals an unhappy experience. So it depends very much on how much data each client will need to render each page or action.

If your application starts to suffer from too many HTTP connections, then you should look at bundling together the data that is always used together -- it wouldn't make sense to send your entire database to every client on every connection :) -- so try to hit the 'lowest hanging fruit' first, and combine the data together that is always used together, to reduce extra connections.

Comment: If website project will success, the traffic should be VERY high, but as the above answers says, I will be looking to group json requests toghether and of course cache it.

Answer (score 1):

My personal philosophy is:

1. The initial page load should be AJAX-free.
2. The page should operate without JavaScript well enough for the user to do all basic tasks.
3. **With** JavaScript, use AJAX in response to user actions and to replace full page reloads with targeted AJAX calls.  After that, use as many AJAX calls as seem reasonable.

Comment: i agree with you but my website is meant to be full ajax/javascript real time app :-)

Comment: @Filip Górny, I respectfully suggest that whoever is paying for the site thinks it is something else. :)  Ajax is a just a technology, a tool.  Make the site work for it's paying purpose; the proper balance of technologies will come from that.  But gazillions of usability and conversion studies say that a site that REQUIRES JavaScript will cost you some percent of customers.

Comment: How about youtube? Try to disable js or flash and browse it ;-)

Comment: And some people refuse to visit Youtube...     Amazon, Youtube, Google, and Microsoft can get away with all sorts of bad practices; will your site be that big?   But, sure, there are some things that you just can't do without Javascript.   PS:  Google controls Youtube, so indexing of AJAX-ified content is not an issue for them ;) .